# CSS: height 100% doesn't make child div fit the whole body, but the nested child takes up the whole body

Tags: html, css

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/ZEqpyjm

I have this simple layout with a single `<div>` inside a `<body>` element:

**HTML**:

```html
<body>

<div id="app" data-v-app="">
    <div id="content-component">
         <div>a lot of text</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        #app {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-color: red;

            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #content-component {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: start;
            align-items: center;

            width: 100%;
            flex: 1 0 auto;

            font-size: 1.2em;


            padding: 2em;

/*
            background-color: blue;
*/
        }
```

Gives the following output:

[image]

The body is yellow, the `#app` div is red. Despite `height: 100%` the `#app` div doesn't take up the whole body.

I also don't understand why the horizontal scrollbar is visible...

If I uncomment the blue background style on the content div, I get this output:

[image]

So despite the parent `app` div (red) not taking up the whole body (yellow), the child content div (blue) takes up the whole body div.

Answer (score 1):

> So despite the parent app div (red) not taking up the whole body (yellow), the child content div (blue) takes up the whole body div.

What you are seeing here, which is especially visible when applying a blue background to the `#content-component` div, is overflow. The `#app` div is 100% of the body, which is the size of the view panel. The body only appears extended because it is accommodating the overflow. In the screenshot below, you see that the body ends where the original viewport ended.

[image: size of the body]

In this second screenshot, you can see that the `#app` div ends in the same spot but there is special shading in [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) to indicate that the content is overflowing.

[image: the content of the app div overflows]

> I also don't understand why the horizontal scrollbar is visible...

You have 100% width/height applied to divs. That will take the full width of the parent and apply that to the child (which has additional padding). To resolve this issue, you can add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the div with both `width: 100%`/`height: 100%` and `padding`.

```
#content-component {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

To make it even more simple, you can remove the 100% properties if that is an option.

I would reduce the CSS to the following to keep the children contained within the body. In other words, no additional CSS is needed to accomplish this layout!

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#app {
  background-color: red;
}

#content-component {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That layout is not the end goal, this: https://codepen.io/faltherr/pen/YzpyLWW is. And the linked layout uses `height: 100%` on `html` and `body` elements. I also need the `content-component` to have `display: flex` as its easiest for positioning its child elements. I use `vue` however which automatically wraps everything inside an `#app` `div`

Comment: Why does the `#content-component` accomodate the overflow, while its parent `#app` doesn't?

Comment: `#content-component` doesn't have a height restriction of 100%. If you add that to the CSS, you'll see the same overflow as with `#app`.

Comment: If I remove `height: 100%` the `app` div becomes too small (less than 100% of the page) when there is not much content in the page, thus the footer stops sticking to the bottom...

Answer (score 1):

You should move this `background-color: red;` in your `#content-component` to fill the div with *red* color. And remove this `width: 100%;` in your `#content-component` as it is unnecessary.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/yLRaood)